# How to add the last classification layer in EfficieNet pre-trained model in Pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, image-classification

I'm using the [EfficientNet](https://pypi.org/project/efficientnet-pytorch/) pre-trained model for my **image classification** project in Pytorch, and my purpose is to change the number of classes which is initially 1000 to 4.
However, for that when I try adding a model._fc layer, I keep on seeing this error "EfficientNet' object has no attribute 'classifier". Here is my code (Config.NUM_CLASSES = 4):

```
elif Config.MODEL_NAME == 'efficientnet-b3':
      
    from efficientnet_pytorch import EfficientNet
    model = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b3')
    model._fc= torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model.classifier.in_features, **out_features=Config.NUM_CLASSES**, bias=True)
```

The situation is different when I add model._fc to the end of the Resnet part, it clearly changes the number of output classes to 4 in Resnet-18. Here is the code for that:

`if Config.MODEL_NAME == 'resnet18': model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True) model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model.fc.in_features, out_features=Config.NUM_CLASSES, bias=True)`

The [solution](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning/) is available for TensorFlow and Keras, and I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with that in PyTorch.

Regards,

Far

Comment: Can you provide the link to the pre_trained model?

Comment: Sure, here is the [Link](https://pypi.org/project/efficientnet-pytorch/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EfficentNet class doesn't have attribute `classifier`, you need to change `in_features=model.classifier.in_features` to `in_features=model._fc.in_features`.

```
import torchvision.models as models

NUM_CLASSES = 4

#EfficientNet
from efficientnet_pytorch import EfficientNet
efficientnet = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b3')
efficientnet ._fc= torch.nn.Linear(in_features=efficientnet._fc.in_features, out_features=NUM_CLASSES, bias=True)

#mobilenet_v2
mobilenet = models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True)
mobilenet.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False),
                  nn.Linear(in_features=mobilenet.classifier[1].in_features, out_features=NUM_CLASSES, bias=True))

#inception_v3
inception = models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
inception.fc =  nn.Linear(in_features=inception.fc.in_features, out_features=NUM_CLASSES, bias=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much@Trong Van. It worked. I'm really new to this world. I wonder if you knew the same thing with the other two models MobileNet and InceptionNet. When I add your line of code to them I get this error. "HTTP Error 403: rate limit exceeded.Here is the code:

Comment: elif Config.MODEL_NAME == 'mobilenet-v2':  model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'mobilenet_v2', pretrained=True)
    model._fc= torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model._fc.in_features, out_features=4, bias=True)
    print(model)

Comment: elif Config.MODEL_NAME == 'inception_v3':
    model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'inception_v3',aux_logits=False, pretrained=True)
    model._fc= torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model._fc.in_features, out_features=4, bias=True)
    print(model)

Comment: I never use `torch.hub` before. But it seems error, check [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/33233). I suggest using `torch.vision.models` to download wide-know models. Also, you should check the model attribute, every model's coding style is different from others, so the classifier name may differ. I will edit my answer for inception and mobinet. You can use this as an example

Comment: @Tong Van. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Torchvision >= 0.11 includes EfficientNet, and it does have a classifier attribute. To get the in_features :

```
import torchvision

model = torchvision.models.efficientnet_b5()
num_ftrs = model.classifier[1].in_features
```